# Cannot install rosserial in ros indigo

Tags: rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When tried to install rosserial using `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rosserial` it returns an error `E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-rosserial`

I am using ros indigo on ubuntu 14.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173966/cannot-install-rosserial-in-ros-indigo/) by [robospace](https://answers.ros.org/users/18911/robospace/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While `rosserial` has been released into Indigo (see [debbuild/indigo.html?q=serial](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/indigo.html?q=serial) for instance), it appears it hasn't yet been synced with the main repositories, which could be why apt-get cannot find it.

It *is* currently available from the `ros-shadow-fixed` repository, see [ros-shadow-fixed/pool/ros-indigo-rosserial](http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-rosserial/).

So it appears we'll have to wait for the next 'sync', which will be announced on the mailing lists.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robospace](https://answers.ros.org/users/18911/robospace/) on 2014-06-19**:
Can we use any methods other than apt-get to install rosserial in indigo?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-06-19**:
Sure. If you already have a catkin workspace (for your own pkgs fi), just checkout rosserial into it (look on the wiki for the github url), then build it like any other catkin package. Alternatively (but not really recommended), you could try to download the *.debs and install those using dpkg.

**Comment by [robospace](https://answers.ros.org/users/18911/robospace/) on 2014-06-19**:
Please share the links from which we can get the *,debs, if you know.
Thanks for the help.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-06-19**:
I would build from source, but I already gave the link: go to the ros-shadow-fixed/pool/ros-indigo-rosserial link I posted, go up one level, then down to ros-indigo-rosserial-{client,server,..} you'll find the debs for each supported architecture. Dependency resolution might still fail though.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-06-19**:
If you are using indigo right now, it's still in beta and so you might as well be using ros-shadow-fixed. Update your /etc/apt/sources files to point at ros-shadow-fixed and you should have rosserial.